# Can you install reCAPTCHA on a Yii based project without composer?

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, recaptcha

Can you implement reCaptcha on a website based on Yii Framework, without using Composer?

Comment: Yes. You can use anything on anything without using composer. Composer is just a convenience tool which makes it easier to add things to your project and ensure it has the required dependencies etc. It's essentially a labour-saving device at the end of the day. There's nothing to prevent you from following the same or similar steps manually to include the files you need into your application.

Comment: @ADyson thanks. I have never used Yii before, and suddenly I have to work on a website based on it... I will try to research how it handles forms and which files are responsible for that. Maybe I can make It!

Answer (score -1):

Simple))

1. Download code from recaptcha lib
2. Paste it to project
3. Change namespaces
4. Use this code with new namespace

voila, no composer)